# Push document into sub document in array of mongoose model

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

in my company schema i have a posted job which is type array and will hold subdocuments

companySchema.js

```
PostedJobs : [{
        JobName : { type: String, required : true},
        JobType : { type: String, required : true},
        JobLocation : { type: String, required : true},
        JobSalay: { type: String, required : true}
    }],
```

in my /company route i get all company registered by specific user through `Creator`entity in model

to get that user company i use

```
  router.get('/',  isLoggedIn ,  function(req, res, next) {
    Company.find({'Creator': req.user.id}).then(function(companies) {
        res.render('Company', { "Companies" : companies });
    });
});
```

after getting company i want to visit a specific company page on clicking company name(unique)

```
router.get('/:name' , isLoggedIn , function(req , res , next) {
    var name = req.params.name;
    Company.findOne({Name : name}).then(function(Company) {
         res.render('dashboard',{
            "Company" : Company,
             errors : []
        });
    })
});
```

now i want to post a job to this specific company from a POST route as 
my req.body consist of JobName , JobType , JobLocation and JobSalary which i have assigned to a specific variable  now how should i push this doc to array

POST route

```
router.post('/:name' , isLoggedIn , function(req , res , next) {
    var JobName = req.body.JobName;
    var JobType = req.body.JobType;
    var JobLocation = req.body.JobLocation;
    var Salary = req.body.Salary;
    //push this job to that specific comapny
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the schema of your company, but if you want to add PostedJobs to the companies, you should define an array field in it.

```
router.post('/:name' , isLoggedIn , function(req , res , next) {
    var JobName = req.body.JobName;
    var JobType = req.body.JobType;
    var JobLocation = req.body.JobLocation;
    var Salary = req.body.Salary;
    //push this job to that specific comapny
    // create the postedJob object
    var postedJob = {JobName : JobName, JobType : JobType, JobLocation : JobLocation, JobSalay:Salary};
    // find the company in DB and add the postedJob to its array of postedJobs
    var name = req.params.name;
    Company.findOne({Name : name}).then(function(company) {
        //modify and save the object received via callback
        company.postedJobs.push(postedJob);
        company.save();
    });
});
```

Comment: i had postedJobs of type array which is

Comment: PostedJobs : [{
        JobName : { type: String, required : true},
        JobType : { type: String, required : true},
        JobLocation : { type: String, required : true},
        JobSalay: { type: String, required : true}
    }],